# php calling bash script with multiple commands issue

Tags: php, bash

Below is my demo file for the task

Content of **index.php**

```
shell_exec("./delete.sh param1 params2");
```

The script is executable

Contents of **demo.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
#! /usr/local/bin/php
destination_path=$1
source_path=$2
xpdf/pdftotext source_path destination_path && php textconv.php destination_path final_output
```

The demo.sh script runs fine when executed from **terminal** and is generating desired output, *but not when executed via **index.php**.*

The destination_path is generated but the final_output is not generated. 
Can anyone help ? Is the **&&** creating the issue ?

Comment: does the user running php have the required permissions to execute the bash script ?

Comment: @swifty yes the user has the permission, The script is executing fine but it's executing **half-way** the destination path is genearated by xpdf but the final path is not create by textconv.php

Comment: You should define a shell in the first line of your shell script (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`), it is possible that the webserver is using a different shell than your user where variables are handled differently (e.g. must be prepended with a `$`).

Comment: Another note, you can add `2>&1` to the end of the command to redirect error messages to stdout. Then you can use `$output = shell_exec('...'); echo $output` to find errors.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider good catch have updated my answer. The shebang was already included just forgot to mention it.

Comment: `$output = shell_exec('...'); echo $output` have tried this no output

Comment: Your shebang line is invalid (remove the space after the !). Also, you can only define one interpreter in the first line, all other lines starting with # will be interpreted as a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92011/discussion-between-akashbhardwaj-and-gerald-schneider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GeraldSchneider Thanks for the prompt comments, it helped majorly in comming to the conclusion.

**Firstly**, The shebang i used was wrong i had to remove space in between

**Secondly**, I can use only one inetrpreter in first line so I remove php from up there and used it in my command instead as follows

```
xpdf/pdftotext source_path destination_path && /usr/local/bin/php textconv.php destination_path final_output
```

**Lastly** for debugging purpose adding 2>&1 was a good way

***Final Script***

```
#!/bin/bash
destination_path=$1
source_path=$2
xpdf/pdftotext source_path destination_path && /usr/local/bin/php textconv.php destination_path final_output
```

Executing it as

```
$output = shell_exec("./delete.sh param1 params2 2>&1");
echo $output;
```